# How to use threads in python

Tags: python, multithreading

I want to use it for reading values in 17770 files and to add all of them at the end to one dictionary object. I have a machine with 8 cores.

This is the code

```
def run_item_preprocess ():
    scores = {};
    for i in range(1,17771):
        filename1 = "x_" + str(i) + ".txt";
        lines1 = open(filename1).readlines();
        Item1 = {};
        for line in lines1:
            tokens = line.split(',');
            Item1[int(tokens[1])] = int(tokens[2]);
        for j in range(1,17771):
            if j == i:
                continue;
            filename2 = "x_" + str(i) + ".txt";
            lines2 = open(filename2).readlines();
            Item2 = {};
            for line in lines2:
                tokens = line.split(',');
                u = int(tokens[1]);
                r = int(tokens[2]);
                if u in Item1:
                    Item2[u] = r;
            if i not in scores:
                scores[i] = {};
            scores[i]= (s(Item1,Item2),j);
```

Comment: I am looking for someone who could help me in that ... I posted my code

Comment: Am I reading this wrong? You're trying to open each of your 17770 files 17770 times?

Comment: Before you think about making it run in multiple threads, you need to make sure the code runs correctly as a single thread. I seriously doubt that this code does what you want it to do. (315772900 file reads?)

Comment: yes ... I have to do that ... and all the files together are 2.3 Gb

Comment: Yes, but opening files 300 million times is not the answer. A database might help. I'm trying to work out what you're actually doing with the code.

Comment: Can you describe what it's supposed to do?

Comment: I don't have enough memory to store what all files have. So I had to open two files at a time and take some similar characteristics. I had no choice but to open the files two at a time and to make sure I am not opening the same file twice. To improve that I need to open the whole 17770 at the same time.

Comment: I have the data on files and I don't have the option to put them in database

Comment: It would probably be quicker to run through the files once to add them to a database, then process them from there. SQLite and shelve are quite easy to use. In any case, your current script will try to store all the data you're using in memory, while still ignoring it and reopening files.

Comment: You're ultimately dealing with values that you call "scores". Scores usually have a limited range (say, 0 to 100, or 0 to 1000.) If that's your situation, then perhaps you can take advantage of that fact by treating the scores themselves as array indices; at each array index, you can track where you found scores matching that index value. That might save you a *lot* of space.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the wonderful [multiprocessing](http://docs.python.org/library/multiprocessing) module. It lets you parallelise code, using processes not threads. This will use all cores.

An important difference is that processes don't share memory; a queue will help with the reduce step.

Comment: Note that the OP says that s/he needs to "add all of them at the end to one dictionary object." That might make multiprocessing problematic.

Comment: The dictionary doesn't have to be shared; there would be a lot of contention if it was.

Answer (score 1):

Here's some good parts of the python library reference to start with.

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/threading.html

http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/_thread.html

As for how to use threads effectively, I recommend you google 'python thread tutorial' or something like that.

Answer (score 0):

How do you think that using threads would help with this?

Although Python supports threading, the standard implementation (CPython) executes [only one thread at a time](http://wiki.python.org/moin/GlobalInterpreterLock). Hence it's hard to see how this would make the process run faster, even on multiple cores.

(If you're using JPython or IronPython, though, this restriction doesn't apply.)

Comment: well .. I have 8 cores on my machine

Comment: Yes, and assuming that you're using CPython, only one of these cores would be running a Python thread at any moment. How does this help?

Comment: It's not clear what the code is supposed to do, so it's hard to say if it'll work on 1 thread or 8. But it doesn't look to me as if this Python code can be sped up by using threads.